# Function not running correctly on azure functions in python

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-functions, intel

I have a script that I want to run in azure functions, the script converts the binary data to a readable array based data format. When I run it on my intel computer, it runs fine and the outputs it gives are correct in form of arrays. When I upload on azure function on the cloud, the function gives no errors but the output arrays are not correct.
I am using JIT/numba in my script to speed up the process.
I am unable to identify what is going wrong, I believe it is some kind of environment that I am supposed to make to get the correct outputs, because I have tried working the same script in a docker container and it is also giving incorrect outputs.

Can anyone guide me on how to approach the problem? Can I replicate my local machines environment on the docker container or azure cloud.

Comment: Did you need to install numba on your local machine to use it?

Comment: @jarrad_obrien yes, it required to install numba

Comment: How are you uploading the code to the Function App?

Comment: @jarrad_obrien I am using VScode to upload the code to function app. Numba is mentioned in the requirements.txt file.

Comment: Even if I remove the JIT decorator from the script, I still get incorrect outputs. So I don't think so it is numba causing the problem, but some other environmental changes.

Comment: I was going to ask if requirements.txt had been included properly :P Are you able to update your post with the code?

Comment: @jarrad_obrien I am still stuck on this problem. I have been able to debug it to quiet an extent, if you are able to help me with it please let me know. So a function in the code reads the binary data byte by byte, I have defined the datatype of first 3 columns as ULONG, when the function reads it in my local machine it reads it correctly as 4 bytes but when it reads in a docker container or azure function, it reads it as 8bytes. That is why I am getting wrong values.

Comment: I am using fromfile(g , dtype = record_dtype , count = records ) command to read the bytes from the file. g is the file name, record_dtype is an array like [('SECONDS','L'),('NANOSECONDS','L')...]
and records is the number of total rows in the file.